# Keep getting compile error: Sub or Function not defined when trying to run my routine

Tags: excel, vba, loops, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get the following vba code to run in excel but keep getting an "Sub or Function not defined" error.  I'm hoping someone can help for I'm on a time crunch.

```
Sub timeFormat2()
  Dim timeArray() As Variant
  Dim hour As String
  Dim min As String
  Dim tempMin As String
    
  rTimeCol = "d"
  
  For i = 2 To 5

        'Only hour exist
        If ((InStr(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "h") > 0) And (InStr(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "m") = 0)) Then
          timeArray = Split(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "h")
          hour = timeArray(1)
          min = "0"
          Range("v" & i).Value = Trim(hour)
          Range("w" & i).Value = min
          Exit For
        
        'Only minutes exist
        ElseIf ((InStr(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "h") = 0) And (InStr(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "m") > 0)) Then
          'timeArray = Split(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "m")
          tempMin = Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value
          hour = "0"
          min = Right(tempMin, Len(tempMin) - 1)
          Range("v" & i).Value = hour
          Range("w" & i).Value = Trim(min)
        
        Else 'hour and minutes
         'If InStr(Range("e2").Value, "h") > 0 Then
          timeArray = Split(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, "h")
          hour = timeArray(1)
          timeArray = Split(Range("rTimeCol" & i).Value, " ")
          
          min = Right(timeArrary(2), Len(timeArray(2)) - 1)
          Range("v" & i).Value = Trim(hour)
          Range("w" & i).Value = Trim(min)
          'Exit For is not necessary with the Else clause
        End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Typo: `timeArrary`. Also `Next cell` should be `Next i` or just `Next`. Suggestion: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module to flag undeclared variables.

Comment: `Range("rTimeCol" & i` ?? `rTimeCol` is a variable so should not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are like `12m` or `10h` or `4h 36m` then try this;

```vb
Sub timeFormat3()
    Const COL_TIME = "C"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 5
       Cells(i, "V").Resize(1, 2) = hhmm(Cells(i, COL_TIME))
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Function hhmm(s As String) As Variant

    Dim ar, i As Integer, m As Integer, h As Integer
    ar = Split(s, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
        If InStr(ar(i), "m") Then
           m = Replace(ar(i), "m", "")
        ElseIf InStr(ar(i), "h") Then
           h = Replace(ar(i), "h", "")
        End If
    Next
    hhmm = Array(h, m)

End Function
```